# Markov Chain, Conditional Independence

Tags: symbols, mathematics

Is the following symbol standard or is it defined in some package? If not, how would you implement this symbol in LaTeX?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A couple of ideas

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\fooA{\mathrel{-\mkern-3mu{\circ}\mkern-3mu-}}

\usepackage{amssymb}
\newcommand*\fooB{\mathrel{{\multimap}\mkern-3mu{-}\mkern-12mu{-}}}

\begin{document}

$X \fooA Z \fooA Y$\par
$\scriptstyle X \fooA Z \fooA Y$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle X \fooA Z \fooA Y$

\smallskip

$X \fooB Z \fooB Y$\par
$\scriptstyle X \fooB Z \fooB Y$\par
$\scriptscriptstyle X \fooB Z \fooB Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Unfortunately the left bar on `\multimap` is longer than a minus sign so I had to guess the `-12mu`.

*Caveat emptor*: these work also in `\scriptstyle`, but not as well in `\scriptscriptstyle`, especially the first one (see picture).

Comment: Thank you @campa for your help.

Answer (score 3):

My code uses `\circ` in the middle of two minus signs (called `\relbar` in order to make it a relation symbol). The amount of backing up depends on the current math style; defining it in a separate macro is handy if you need to tailor the symbol to other math fonts.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\condind}{%
  \relbar
  \condindbackup
  \mathrel{\circ}%
  \condindbackup
  \relbar
}
\newcommand{\condindbackup}{%
  \mathrel{%
    \mathchoice{\mkern-3mu}{\mkern-3mu}{\mkern-3.5mu}{\mkern-4mu}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

$X \condind Y$

$\scriptstyle X \condind Y$

$\scriptscriptstyle X \condind Y$

\end{document}
```

[image]

For instance, with `newtxmath` the amount of kerning can be chosen to be the same `-3mu` in all styles, so you could abbreviate into

```
\newcommand{\condindbackup}{\joinrel}
```

in this case, because `\joinrel` is exactly `\mathrel{\mkern-3mu}}`. A proposal:

```
\newcommand{\condindbackup}{%
  \mathrel{%
    % the next line is for Computer Modern
    \mathchoice{\mkern-3mu}{\mkern-3mu}{\mkern-3.5mu}{\mkern-4mu}%
    % the next line is for NewTX
    %\mkern-3mu
    % the next line is for ...
  }%
}
```

Comment: Thank you @egreg for this solution.